# PHP how can i append data into a serialized array

Tags: php, serialization, append

If I have a serialized array... how can I append more values to it? Should I unserialize it first -> add data and then serialize it again?

Comment: Obviously serializing will be the best way to go. However, if you have a huge serialized array, repeating this process over and over is going to be very inefficient. Does the array NEED to be serialized in the first place?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

```
function addItem($serializedArray, $item)
{
   $a = unserialize($serializedArray);
   $a[] = $item;
   return serialize($a);
}
```

Comment: If he's going to be using a function, it may just be more efficient to pass $serializedArray by reference and have it append the new item directly to the referenced array rather than returning the new value and setting it again.

Comment: @BraedenP.  That sounds like it could be a good improvement.  I think I would also take a bit more time to name the function and its variables.

Answer (score 3):

Unserializing is the way to go, definitely. Unless you have a huge string, it'd be strongly recommended, unless you want to make your own strict interpreter.

Changing anything from a serialized array/object should be done very carefully - a single extra character would break everything if you don't update all previous numbers defining each piece of structure!

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is the only (reliable) way