# append data in serialized array with php

Tags: php

I am writing a php script for creating serialized array as follow:

```
$x=Array();
  $x[0]=$_GET['fname'];
  $x[1]=$_GET['lname'];
  $str=serialize($x);
  print $str;
  $y=$_GET['hf'];
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("formdemo", $con);
    $sql="update rohit set data='$str' where fid='$y'";
```

now I want to append more data on this array. what should I do for that

Thanx

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658616/php-how-can-i-append-data-into-a-serialized-array?rq=1

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you do not escape data passed to your script. You have to do it with:

```
$x[0] = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['fname'] );
```

Also you do not need to set index, so:

```
$x[] = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['fname'] );
```

It will append data to the end of array.

If you want to add new data to the existing serialized array, you need to unserialize it, add data and serialize again:

```
$x   = unserialize($x);
$x[] = 'something else';
$x   = serialize($x);
```

Comment: "*First of all*" should read, "*First of all, don't use `mysql_*` functions*" ;)

Comment: You will not save the world. I do not make ops app refactor, just highlight SQL Injection problem.

Answer (score 1):

You must unserialized array add value and serialize again.

```
function add($serializedArray, $item)
{
   $array = unserialize($serializedArray);
   $array[] = $item;
   return serialize($array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pull it out of the DB, unserialize it, add data, serialize it, then update it again:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "formdemo");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT data FROM rohit WHERE fid = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['hf']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($x);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

$x = unserialize($x['data']);
$x[] = "new data";
$x = serialize($x);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("update rohit set data=? where fid=?");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $x, $_GET['hf']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I have applied all of the methods but i am getting the same problem   unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes

Comment: and, did you echo $x and see what it is? Do you have data in the DB? I skipped the error-checking code for brevity. Each of the results-accessing methods should only be used inside of a check for rows returned. See here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php

Comment: when i am using print_r then it is returning the array but when i am updating the table again then it is returning the error unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes

Comment: That error sounds like it is not seeing serialized data in what is being passed, which means the database row is likely not being properly set. If you inspect the data at various points (including in the DB in something like PHPMyAdmin or the terminal), you should be able to track down the issue.